# Point a plugin into to a local file

Tags: craft3, url, plugin-feedme

This should have been easy. But, I am dorking something up.

I am trying to point FeedMe to a local file.

In Finder, the file is located under `/Users/shellyar/Desktop`.  I also tried `file:////Users/shellyar/Desktop'.  Neither worked.

[image]

Comment: I had the same, but I think that this is because the plugin tries to get your file using Guzzle (with a GET request), regardless of the url being local. Didn't have the time to file an issue (yet), but maybe you can do so on https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/issues?

Comment: Looks like it does try to use `file_get_contents` first for local filesystem files.  https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/blob/53ff2c436ef95a43a8b7ac72755c602eaad7f448/src/services/DataTypes.php#L131  Have you tried the absolute path? `/Users/shellyar/Desktop/myfile`

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in [3.0.0-beta.10](https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/releases/tag/3.0.0-beta.10). Additionally you can use the concept of aliases in your URL for all sorts of variables:

`@web/assets/data/clients.xml`

Which would be related to your web root.